# How to choose Google Chrome or Firefox as default web browser in Automation test using Robot Framework in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm learning to create an automation script using the Robot Framework. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 OS.
I want to automate the web [www.carvago.com](http://www.carvago.com) to do a car search. I've imported RPA.Browser Library, and made Search Car keywords where there are steps for Open Available Browser.
My question, how to choose Google Chrome as the default web browser? Because, when I run the script, the web browser is opened from VS Code, not from the web browser on my laptop like Google Chrome or Firefox.
Can anyone provide help and solutions? Thank you

Here I share my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Template robot main suite.
Library             Collections
Library             MyLibrary
Library             RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library             RPA.Excel.Files
Resource            keywords.robot
Variables           MyVariables.py

*** Keywords ***
Read Excel
    Open Workbook       /home/maaofficial/Documents/test_escape_list.xlsx
    ${list}     Read Worksheet      header=true
    Log To Console      ${list}
    Close Workbook
    FOR         ${index}    IN      @{list}
        Search Car      ${index}
    END

Search Car
    [Arguments]         ${index}
    Go To   %{C_URL}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Element Is Visible       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]
    Press Keys      NONE    ${index}[make]
    Sleep   333ms
    Press Keys      NONE    TAB
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
    Sleep   500ms
    Press Keys      NONE    ${index}[model]
    Sleep   333ms
    Press Keys      NONE    TAB
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/input
    Sleep   500ms
    Press Keys      NONE    ${index}[max_km]
    Sleep   500ms
    # Click Minimize Button
    Click Element                        xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]
    Sleep  333ms
    # Click Button Search
    Click Element                         xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[1]/button
    # Click Sort by Button
    Wait Until Element Is Visible         xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div    10s
    Sleep   3s
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
    Sleep   3s
    # Click Lowest Price
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/p
    Sleep   5s

*** Tasks ***
Main
    Open Available Browser
    Read Excel
```

Comment: Use `Open Browser` keyword and pass the browser name as argument, name can be "Chrome" or "Firefox" ..

Answer (score 0):

you have to download the web driver..

then, you fallow this code:

```
 Create Webdriver   |    Chrome/ Firefox   |   executable_path="    .exe" (place the file manger location of the web driver you installed)
```

Thank you!